Are personal attacks authorized on Politics SE?
A comment on this question Why DPRK troops in Ukraine are such a big deal?

You seem to be fishing for a specific answer given the comment you've written under one of the answers that it "doesn't answer your question".

I am looking for a definitive statement from the moderators, whether this kind of attacks are authorized on Politics SE.
Another one in the same thread:

I find it insane that someone posts a dupe, someone figures out its a dupe, and then after that no less than six people go and answer it. Seriously...


This question is similar to: What is a "push question"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That is a comment suggesting that you appear to be asking a push question which is off topic on the site and not an attack against you.

@JoeW this question is not at all about the nature of a question, but about the nature of the comment.

My comment is about the nature of the comment which is a suggestion that your question is a push question and it is not an attack on you.

@JoeW the comment is not criticizing the question - it is directed against its author.

@JoeW English is not my first language, so perhaps I am mistaken about what "You" means?

I added a link to the question that the comment is on https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89862/why-dprk-troops-in-ukraine-are-such-a-big-deal

@JoeW this is a violation of SE policy, since you point a finger at a specific user, while I didn't mention who it is to preserve their privacy.

It is critical to understand the context of the comment and this is done all the time on meta.

JoeW's edit doesn't violate policy in any way. Yes, it is slightly more trivial now to work out which user you are referring to, but the question remains focused on the action and not the user.

@F1Krazy * edit doesn't violate policy in any way.* - Your are mistaken - moderators here are known to close questions, because they cited another user's answer/question. But we could ask them to state their policy on this subject as well.

You asked essentially the same question here before, about the same user.  It wasn't well received then either.  The comment may not be particularly friendly but most people would not be that offended by it.  Not to the point of raising as a question on meta anyway, where it seems fairly frivolous.  And you did specifically point at them at the time, making your protestations of privacy-minding seem rather hollow.

@ItalianPhilosopher You asked essentially the same question - indeed, it appears to be habitual abuse, deserving suspension. And the fact that moderators are not doing anything about such behavior does not speak in their favor. You are right that such abuse is quite common in this community, to the extent that people do not take offense... but by the SE standards this is quite low.

As a recipient myself of much more pointed and unfriendly attacks coming from yourself in the past, I find your outrage rather misplaced.  OK, you and they don't get along.  Ask better questions and/or ignore them.  I tend to avoid you and am only putting this in - as I did in the linked question before - because I find this a weak, rhetorical, attempt to get someone in trouble for something that was not a big deal to start with.

@ItalianPhilosopher I find your outrage rather misplaced - there is no outrage, but merely an effort to enforce the SE code of conduct - no need to overthink it or project your own emotions on it. Furthermore, if you feel that any of my past comments were offensive, you should have brought them up here, as per SE policy... rather then engaging in petty vengeance (I know from the comment above that you won't get offended by this wording.)

I thank you for your consideration about my own feelings.  I can't reasonably deny that there is a bit of amusement from me in pushing back, so no I am not offended by "petty vengeance"  ;-)  But really you would be better served by a) not getting so offended so quickly, given your own tendencies b) deleting both these Q and c) resorting to flagging, when appropriate, just like everyone else.  And I probably would make these recommendations to other people in the same circumstances, even had I not had any interactions with them.

Oh, and concerning people (newbies in this instance) who are surprised at people voting to close and answering?  That is fairly understandable - though "insane" might have been phrased differently.  I have engaged in that at least once - VTC + answer.  And you were annoyed enough to open a Q in meta complaining about it.  L'hospital qui se moque de la charite and all that.  See, no need to invoke "higher level moderators".

@ItalianPhilosopher you constantly speak about outrage, complaining, wining - it seems that you misunderstand that people's motivations for the same actions can be quite different from yours, and dictated by rather rational reasons. This is actually the core of our disagreement in political sphere - rationality vs your likes and dislikes.

Neither of those comments are personal attacks. Commenting on the behaviour of you or others is not attacking someone.

Personal attacks are not allowed on Politics Stack Exchange.
However, people simply criticizing what you write is not a personal attack.

"You seem to be fishing for a specific answer given the comment you've written under one of the answers that it "doesn't answer your question"." - As I am not the native English speaker, perhaps you could explain what you refers to in this comment?  Also "I find it insane that someone posts a dupe, someone figures out its a dupe [...]" Could we request the opinion of higher level moderators on this case?

@Wagthemainstreammediadog "Higher level moderators" would be the community team. You can get in touch with them and explain the situation via the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page.

@F1Krazy don't worry, I know how to do this - I just don't want to go straight over the head of the Politics SE team - perhaps they discuss the problem among themselves and adopt a more coherent policy than * you can be insulted, because we disagree with your content*.
